# React-Router with Webpack-Dev-Server setup

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

New to webpack, I am having trouble setting up correctly using React-Router and Webpack-Dev-Server.

The reason why I want to setup this way is to take the advantage of using `webpack-hot-middleware` to reload the page every time I change something in the code.

Although I am able to render correctly for the IndexPage, if I type manually at a different entry point in the URL, webpack will think I am retrieving somewhere else, where in reality it is located in the React-Router.

Here's current setup (or [Github repository](https://github.com/Neotriz/fcc-voter)):

**webpack.config**

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './src/client/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },{
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      loaders: ['style','css','sass'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

**server.js for webpack**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

var app = express();
var compiler = webpack(config);
//
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));

app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:3000/');
})
```

**src/client/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/app';
import VotesContainer from './containers/votes-container';
import Welcome from './components/welcome'
import reducers from './reducers';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="allposts" component={VotesContainer} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('#project'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "simple-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --require ignore-styles  --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "dev": "nodemon src/server/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "proxy-middleware": "^0.15.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.
I was right all along, I simply forgot to reset my server.

Initially, I had set as so:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

After restarting my server and have `/` replace with `*` did the trick